# dijit/form/Select setStore selecting first item in the list

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I'm trying to load the Select widget's list post-startup.  I have already made calls to the backend to load both my model and the list.

Calling setStore() on the Select is loading the items into the widget, but also selecting the first item in the list, and changing the bound model property to the first item.

I've also tried calling setStore() with the second parameter (selectedValue), but this appears to have no impact.

I have thrown together a hack which first calls setStore() to introduce the list the the widget (selecting the first item), and then a call to set("value") to set the widget value and model property back to the initial value.  This hack causes the change event to fire on the widget during the form load which is not desirable.  I could disconnect/reconnect the handler, but that is just more hack.

To recreate this, make a slight change to the dojox/mvc/tests/test_mvc_new_form-kitchensink.html.

First comment out the store in the construction of the select:

```
        var sel = new Select({
        //  store: store,
            loadChildrenOnOpen: true,
        //  value: 1,   
            value: at(selctrl, 'number') // bind to model.number
        }, document.getElementById('sel'));
```

Then set the store in a setTimeout() call (after startup):

```
        sel.startup();
        setTimeout(function () {
            sel.setStore(store);
        }, 1000);
```

If you intend to test with the declarative example, you'll need to remove the 'store' property from data-dojo-props attribute on the appropriate select element.

The field is bound to the 'number' field in the selctrl controller, which is initially set to "1".  Once setStore is called on the Select, both the widget and the bound model property will be set to the first item in the list, which in this case is "8".

Here's the test page with modifications to both the programmatic and declarative Select widgets:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Data-bound Form element Kitchen Sink test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "css/app-format.css";
        @import "../../../dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
        label {
            text-align: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad:1,isDebug:1,async:1,mvc:{debugBindings:1}" src="../../../dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var store, selctrl, decselctrl, numspinctrl; 
    var filctrl, decfilctrl;
    var comboctrl, deccomboctrl;
    var datectrl, decdatectrl; 
    var sliderctrl, decsliderctrl;
    var numspinctrl, decnumspinctrl;
    var simpTActrl, decsimpTActrl;
    var textareactrl, dectextareactrl;
    var deccalctrl, deccolorctrl;

    require([
        'dojo/_base/kernel',
        "dojo/_base/declare",
        'dojo/parser',
        'dojo/ready',
        'dojox/mvc',
        'dojox/mvc/at',         
        'dijit/registry',
        'dijit/_WidgetBase',
        'dijit/form/TextBox',
        'dijit/form/Button',
        'dijit/form/Select',
        'dijit/form/FilteringSelect',
        'dijit/form/ComboBox',
        'dijit/form/DateTextBox',
        'dijit/form/HorizontalSlider',
        'dijit/form/NumberSpinner',
        'dijit/form/SimpleTextarea',
        'dijit/form/Textarea',
        'dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore',
        "dojo/Stateful",
        "dojox/mvc/getStateful",
        "dojox/mvc/EditModelRefController",
        'dijit/Calendar',
        'dijit/ColorPalette',
        'dojox/mvc/Group',
        'dojox/mvc/Output',
        'dojo/date/locale'
        ], function(kernel, declare, parser, ready, mvc, at, registry, _WidgetBase, TextBox, Button, Select, FilteringSelect, ComboBox, DateTextBox, 
                    HorizontalSlider, NumberSpinner, SimpleTextarea, Textarea, ItemFileReadStore, Stateful, getStateful, EditModelRefController, 
                    Calendar, ColorPalette){
        //window.at = at;

        var alreadyset = false; 
        var data = [
            {id: '1',name:"one"},
            {id: '2',name:"two"},
            {id: '3',name:"three"},
            {id: '4',name:"four"},
            {id: '5',name:"five"},
            {id: '6',name:"six"},
            {id: '7',name:"seven"},
            {id: '8',name:"eight"},
            {id: '9',name:"nine"},
            {id: '10',name:"ten"},
            {id: '11',name:"eleven"},
            {id: '12',name:"twelve"},
            {id: '13',name:"thirteen"}
          ];
        store = new ItemFileReadStore({
            data: {
                identifier: 'id',
                label: 'name',
                items: data
            }
        });

        var data2 = {
            identifier: "value",
            label: "label",
            items: [
                {value: "1", label: "one"},
                {value: "2", label: "two"},
                {value: "3", label: "three"},
                {value: "4", label: "four"},
                {value: "5", label: "five"},
                {value: "6", label: "six"},
                {value: "7", label: "seven"},
                {value: "8", label: "eigth"},
                {value: "9", label: "nine"},
                {value: "10", label: "ten"},
                {value: "11", label: "eleven"},
                {value: "12", label: "twelve"},
                {value: "13", label: "thirteen"},
                {value: "14", label: "fourteen"}
            ]
        };

        selctrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "1"})});
        decselctrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "1"})});

        // create models for filtering selects
        filctrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "2"})});
        decfilctrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "2"})});

        // create models for ComboBoxes
        comboctrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "three"})});
        deccomboctrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "three"})});

        // create a model for DateTextBox
        datectrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "2011-04-04"})});
        decdatectrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "2011-04-04"})});

        // create a model for Slider
        sliderctrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "5"})});
        decsliderctrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "5"})});

        // create a model for NumberSpinner
        numspinctrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "6"})});
        decnumspinctrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "6"})});

        // create a model for SimpleTextArea
        simpTActrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "7"})});
        decsimpTActrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "7"})});

        // create a model for TextArea
        textareactrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "8"})});
        dectextareactrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({number: "8"})});

        // create a model for dijit.Calendar
        deccalctrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({date: "Mon Apr 04 2011 01:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"})});

        // create a model for dijit.ColorPalette
        deccolorctrl = new EditModelRefController({sourceModel: new Stateful({code: "#000000"})});

        // Handle the programmatic creation of widgets here:

        // create the select, textbox, output and button            
        var sel = new Select({
        //  store: store,
            loadChildrenOnOpen: true,
        //  value: 1,   
            value: at(selctrl, 'number') // bind to model.number
        }, document.getElementById('sel'));

        var text = new TextBox({
            //id: "seltext",
            value: at(selctrl, 'number') // bind to model.number
        }, document.getElementById('seltext'));         
        text.startup();

        var selOutput = new mvc.Output({
            value: at(selctrl, 'number') // bind to model.number
        }, document.getElementById('selOutput'));
        selOutput.startup();

        var reset1 = new Button({
            onClick: function(){ selctrl.reset(); },
            id: "selReset",
            label: "Reset"
        }, document.getElementById('reset1'));
        reset1.startup();


        sel.watch('value', function () {
            //console.log('sel value changed', arguments);
        });

        text.watch('value', function () {
            //console.log('text value changed', arguments);
        });

        sel.startup();
        setTimeout(function () {
            sel.setStore(store);
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            var decsel = registry.byId("decsel");
            decsel.setStore(store);
        }, 1000);


        // create the filtering select, textbox, output and button          
        var filsel = new FilteringSelect({
            store: store,
            value: at(filctrl,'number') // bind to ctrl.number
        }, document.getElementById('filsel'));
        filsel.startup();

        var filtext = new TextBox({
            value: at(filctrl,'number') // bind to ctrl.number
        }, document.getElementById('filtext'));
        filtext.startup();

        var filoutput = new mvc.Output({
            value: at(filctrl,'number') // bind to ctrl.number
        }, document.getElementById('filoutput'));           
        filoutput.startup();

        var filreset = new Button({
            onClick: function(){filctrl.reset();},
            id: "filReset",
            label: "Reset"
        }, document.getElementById('filreset'));
        filreset.startup();


        // create the comboBox, textbox, output and button          
        var combo = new ComboBox({
            store: store,
            value: at(comboctrl, 'number') // bind to ctrl.number
        }, document.getElementById('combosel'));

        var combotext = new TextBox({
            value: at(comboctrl, 'number')
        }, document.getElementById('combotext'));

        var combooutput = new mvc.Output({
            value: at(comboctrl, 'number')
        }, document.getElementById('combooutput'));         
        combooutput.startup();

        var comboreset = new Button({
            onClick: function(){comboctrl.reset();},
            id: "comboReset",
            label: "Reset"
        }, document.getElementById('comboreset'));
        comboreset.startup();

        combotext.startup();
        combo.startup();

        // create the dijit.form.DateTextBox, textbox, output and button            
        var dateWid = new DateTextBox({
            value: at(datectrl, 'number') // bind to ctrl.number
        }, document.getElementById('datesel'));

        var datetext = new TextBox({
            value: at(datectrl, 'number')
        }, document.getElementById('datetext'));

        var dateoutput = new mvc.Output({
            value: at(datectrl, 'number')
        }, document.getElementById('dateoutput'));          
        dateoutput.startup();

        var datereset = new Button({
            onClick: function(){datectrl.reset();},
            id: "dateReset",
            label: "Reset"
        }, document.getElementById('datereset'));
        datereset.startup();

        datetext.startup();
        dateWid.startup();

        // create the dijit.form.HorizontalSlider, textbox, output and button           
        var sliderWid = new HorizontalSlider({
                    style:{width:"190px"},
                    minimum:0,
                    maximum:100,
                    discreteValues:21,
            value: at(sliderctrl, 'number') // bind to ctrl.number
        }, document.getElementById('slidersel'));

        var slidertext = new TextBox({
            value: at(sliderctrl, 'number')
        }, document.getElementById('slidertext'));

        var slideroutput = new mvc.Output({
            value: at(sliderctrl, 'number')
        }, document.getElementById('slideroutput'));            
        slideroutput.startup();

        var sliderreset = new Button({
            onClick: function(){sliderctrl.reset();},
            id: "sliderReset",
            label: "Reset"
        }, document.getElementById('sliderreset'));
        sliderreset.startup();

        slidertext.startup();
        sliderWid.startup();

        // create the dijit.form.NumberSpinner, textbox, output and button          
        var numspinWid = new NumberSpinner({
        //  constraints:{max:100,places:0},
            value: at(numspinctrl, 'number') // bind to ctrl.number
        }, document.getElementById('numspinsel'));

        var numspintext = new TextBox({
            value: at(numspinctrl, 'number')
        }, document.getElementById('numspintext'));

        var numspinoutput = new mvc.Output({
            value: at(numspinctrl, 'number')
        }, document.getElementById('numspinoutput'));           
        numspinoutput.startup();

        var numspinreset = new Button({
            onClick: function(){numspinctrl.reset();},
            id: "numspinReset",
            label: "Reset"
        }, document.getElementById('numspinreset'));
        numspinreset.startup();

        numspintext.startup();
        numspinWid.startup();

        // create the dijit.form.SimpleTextarea, textbox, output and button             
        var simpTAWid = new SimpleTextarea({
            style:{height:"20px", width:"180px"},
            value: at(simpTActrl, 'number') // bind to ctrl.number
        }, document.getElementById('simpTAsel'));

        var simpTAtext = new TextBox({
            value: at(simpTActrl, 'number')
        }, document.getElementById('simpTAtext'));

        var simpTAoutput = new mvc.Output({
            value: at(simpTActrl, 'number')
        }, document.getElementById('simpTAoutput'));            
        simpTAoutput.startup();

        var simpTAreset = new Button({
            onClick: function(){simpTActrl.reset();},
            id: "simpTAReset",
            label: "Reset"
        }, document.getElementById('simpTAreset'));
        simpTAreset.startup();

        simpTAtext.startup();
        simpTAWid.startup();

        // create the dijit.form.Textarea, textbox, output and button 
        var textareaWid = new Textarea({
        //  constraints:{max:100,places:0},
            value: at(textareactrl, 'number') // bind to ctrl.number
        }, document.getElementById('textareasel'));

        var textareatext = new TextBox({
            value: at(textareactrl, 'number')
        }, document.getElementById('textareatext'));

        var textareaoutput = new mvc.Output({
            value: at(textareactrl, 'number')
        }, document.getElementById('textareaoutput'));          
        textareaoutput.startup();

        var textareareset = new Button({
            onClick: function(){textareactrl.reset();},
            id: "textareaReset",
            label: "Reset"
        }, document.getElementById('textareareset'));
        textareareset.startup();

        textareatext.startup();
        textareaWid.startup();

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <script type="dojo/require">at: "dojox/mvc/at"</script>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header" style="margin-top: 0px;">
            <div id="navigation"  style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
            <div id="headerInsert"  style="margin-top: 0px;">
                <h2>Data-bound Form Element Kitchen Sink MVC test</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin-top: 0px;">
            <div id="leftNav"></div>
            <div id="mainContent">

                <h2 style="margin-top: 0px;">Programmatic creation of Form elements:</h2>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Widget</label></td>
                            <td><label></label></td>
                            <td><label>Textbox</label></td>
                            <td><label>Output</label></td>
                            <td><label>Model Reset</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="sel">Select:</label></td>
                            <td><div id="sel"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="seltext"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="selOutput"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="reset1" ></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="filsel">FilteringSelect:</label></td>
                            <td><div id="filsel"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="filtext"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="filoutput"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="filreset"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="combosel">ComboBox:</label></td>
                            <td><div id="combosel"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="combotext"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="combooutput"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="comboreset"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="datesel">DateTextBox:</label></td>
                            <td><div id="datesel"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="datetext"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="dateoutput"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="datereset"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="slidersel">Slider:</label></td>
                            <td><div id="slidersel"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="slidertext"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="slideroutput"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="sliderreset"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="numspinsel">NumberSpinner:</label></td>
                            <td><div id="numspinsel"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="numspintext"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="numspinoutput"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="numspinreset"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="simpTAsel">SimpleTextArea:</label></td>
                            <td><div id="simpTAsel"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="simpTAtext"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="simpTAoutput"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="simpTAreset"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="textareasel">TextArea:</label></td>
                            <td><div id="textareasel"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="textareatext"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="textareaoutput"></div></td>
                            <td><div id="textareareset"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <h2>Declarative creation of Form elements:</h2>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Widget</label></td>
                            <td><label></label></td>
                            <td><label>Textbox</label></td>
                            <td><label>Output</label></td>
                            <td><label>Model Reset</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <!--  <td><label for="decsel">Select:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="decsel" style="width: 188px;" 
                                                data-dojo-id="decsel" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select" 
                                                data-dojo-props='name:"decsel",loadChildrenOnOpen: true, value: at(decselctrl, 'number') '>
                                    <option value="1">one</option>
                                    <option value="2">two</option>
                                    <option value="3">three</option>
                                    <option value="4">four</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        --> 
                            <td><label for="decsel">Select:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <!--
                                <select id="decsel" style="width: 188px;" 
                                        data-dojo-id="decsel" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select" 
                                        data-dojo-props='store:store, name:"decsel",loadChildrenOnOpen: true, value: at(decselctrl, "number")'>
                                </select>
                                -->
                                <select id="decsel" style="width: 188px;" 
                                        data-dojo-id="decsel" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select" 
                                        data-dojo-props='name:"decsel",loadChildrenOnOpen: true, value: at(decselctrl, "number")'>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="cell" id="decseltext" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"
                                data-dojo-props="value: at(decselctrl, 'number')"></input>
                            </td>
                            <td><span   id="decselOutput" data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output"
                                        data-dojo-props="value: at(decselctrl, 'number')">
                                ${this.value}
                            </span></td>
                            <td><button id="decselReset" type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" 
                                        data-dojo-props="onClick: function(){decselctrl.reset();}">Reset</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="decfilsel">FilteringSelect:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="decfilsel" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.FilteringSelect"
                                    data-dojo-props='store:store, value: at(decfilctrl, "number")'/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="decfiltext" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"
                                data-dojo-props="value: at(decfilctrl, 'number')"></input>
                            </td>
                            <td><span id="decfilOutput" data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output" 
                                        data-dojo-props="value: at(decfilctrl, 'number')">
                                ${this.value}
                            </span></td>
                            <td><button id="decfilReset" type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" 
                                        data-dojo-props="onClick: function(){decfilctrl.reset();}">Reset</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="deccombosel">ComboBox:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="deccombosel" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ComboBox"
                                    data-dojo-props='store:store, value: at(deccomboctrl, "number")'/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="deccombotext" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"
                                data-dojo-props="value: at(deccomboctrl, 'number')"></input>
                            </td>
                            <td><span id="deccomboOutput" data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output" 
                                        data-dojo-props="value: at(deccomboctrl, 'number')">
                                ${this.value}
                            </span></td>
                            <td><button id="deccomboReset" type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" 
                                        data-dojo-props="onClick: function(){deccomboctrl.reset();}">Reset</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="datesel">DateTextBox:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="decdatesel" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox"
                                    data-dojo-props='store:store, value: at(decdatectrl, "number")'/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="decdatetext" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"
                                data-dojo-props="value: at(decdatectrl, 'number')"></input>
                            </td>
                            <td><span id="decdateOutput" data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output" 
                                        data-dojo-props="value: at(decdatectrl, 'number')">
                                ${this.value}
                            </span></td>
                            <td><button id="decdateReset" type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" 
                                        data-dojo-props="onClick: function(){decdatectrl.reset();}">Reset</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="decslidersel">Slider:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="decslidersel" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.HorizontalSlider"
                                    data-dojo-props='store:store, value: at(decsliderctrl, "number"),
                                                    style:{width:"190px"}, minimum:0, maximum:100, discreteValues:21'/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="decslidertext" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"
                                data-dojo-props="value: at(decsliderctrl, 'number')"></input>
                            </td>
                            <td><span id="decsliderOutput" data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output" 
                                        data-dojo-props="value: at(decsliderctrl, 'number')">
                                ${this.value}
                            </span></td>
                            <td><button id="decsliderReset" type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" 
                                        data-dojo-props="onClick: function(){decsliderctrl.reset();}">Reset</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="decnumspinsel">NumberSpinner:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="decnumspinsel" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.NumberSpinner"
                                    data-dojo-props='store:store, value: at(decnumspinctrl, "number")'/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="decnumspintext" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"
                                data-dojo-props="value: at(decnumspinctrl, 'number')"></input>
                            </td>
                            <td><span id="decnumspinOutput" data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output" 
                                        data-dojo-props="value: at(decnumspinctrl, 'number')">
                                ${this.value}
                            </span></td>
                            <td><button id="decnumspinReset" type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" 
                                        data-dojo-props="onClick: function(){decnumspinctrl.reset();}">Reset</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="decsimpTAsel">SimpleTextArea:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="decsimpTAsel" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Textarea"
                                    data-dojo-props='store:store, value: at(decsimpTActrl, "number")'/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="decsimpTAtext" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"
                                data-dojo-props="value: at(decsimpTActrl, 'number')"/>
                            </td>
                            <td><span id="decsimpTAOutput" data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output" 
                                        data-dojo-props="value: at(decsimpTActrl, 'number')">
                                ${this.value}
                            </span></td>
                            <td><button id="decsimpTAReset" type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" 
                                    data-dojo-props="onClick: function(){decsimpTActrl.reset();}">Reset</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="dectextareasel">TextArea:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="dectextareasel" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Textarea"
                                    data-dojo-props='store:store, value: at(dectextareactrl, "number")'/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="dectextareatext" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"
                                data-dojo-props="value: at(dectextareactrl, 'number')"/>
                            </td>
                            <td><span id="dectextareaOutput" data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output" 
                                        data-dojo-props="value: at(dectextareactrl, 'number')">
                                ${this.value}
                            </span></td>
                            <td><button id="dectextareaReset" type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" 
                                    data-dojo-props="onClick: function(){dectextareactrl.reset();}">Reset</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <h2>Test data-bound dijit.Calendar:</h2>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>Widget</label></td>
                            <td><label></label></td>
                            <td><label>Textbox</label></td>
                            <td><label>Output</label></td>
                            <td><label>Model Reset</label></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="deccal">Calendar:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="cell"  id="deccal" data-dojo-id="deccal"  data-dojo-type="dijit.Calendar" 
                                        data-dojo-props='value: at(deccalctrl, "date") '/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="cell" id="deccaltext" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"
                                data-dojo-props="value: at(deccalctrl, 'date')"></input>
                            </td>
                            <td><span   id="deccalOutput" data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output"
                                        data-dojo-props="value: at(deccalctrl, 'date')">
                                ${this.value}
                            </span></td>
                            <td><button id="deccalReset" type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" 
                                        data-dojo-props="onClick: function(){deccalctrl.reset();}">Reset</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="deccolor">ColorPalette:</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <div id="deccolor" data-dojo-type="dijit.ColorPalette" 
                                        data-dojo-props='palette:"3x4", value: at(deccolorctrl, "code")'></div>                             
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="cell" id="deccolortext" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.TextBox"
                                data-dojo-props="value: at(deccolorctrl, 'code')"></input>
                            </td>
                            <td><span   id="deccolorOutput" data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output"
                                        data-dojo-props="value: at(deccolorctrl, 'code')">
                                ${this.value}
                            </span></td>
                            <td><button id="deccolorReset" type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" 
                                        data-dojo-props="onClick: function(){deccolorctrl.reset();}">Reset</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ItemFileReadStore was replaced by a simple array passed to addOption.  The store was overkill for my solution.

At the point in time when all data is received from the backend (model and lists) an array is built for each Select with the selected item indicated to reflect the current  bound model.property.  The only issue with this implementation is the need to call removeOption and then addOption if the list needs to be rebound to its list due to changing context in the page.

If anyone has insight into why the Select with Store was behaving as described above, please post an explanation.